# Click event of a button inside an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code, when I call "some_function" from outside the object, it alerts zero.
When I click "some_button", "some_function" is called too, but it alerts undefined in this case.
What's the problem ?

```
some_object = {
    some_variable: 0,
    some_button: $('<input />', {
        type: "button",
        value: "Click Me"
    }),
    some_function: function () {
        alert(this.some_variable);
    },
    init: function () {
        $("body").append(this.some_button);
        this.some_button.click(this.some_function); // Result is undefined
    }
}
some_object.init();
some_object.some_function(); // Result is 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
some_function: function () {
    alert(this.some_variable);
},
```

this refers to the button not to the object.
try this :

```
some_object = {
some_variable: 0,
some_button: $('<input />', {
    type: "button",
    value: "Click Me"
}),
some_function: function (variable) {
    alert(variable);
},
init: function () {
    $("body").append(this.some_button);
    $this = this;
    $this.some_button.click(function(){
        $this.some_function($this.some_variable);
    });  
}
}
some_object.init();
some_object.some_function(some_object.some_variable);
```

Comment: some_object = {
some_variable: 1,
some_button: $('<input />', {
    type: "button",
    value: "Click Me"
}),
some_function: function () {
    alert(some_object.some_variable);
},
init: function () {
    $("body").append(this.some_button);
    $this = this;
    $this.some_button.click(function(){
        $this.some_function();
    });  
}
}
some_object.init();
some_object.some_function();

Answer (score 0):

It Happens because, when you register a click handler, this refers to a button element, not the object. instead you can call:

```
alert(some_object.some_variable);
```

Answer (score 0):

At this statement this.some_function, the 'this'  is refers the clicked button not object 'some_object'.

I think your statement should be like this

```
 this.some_button.click(some_object.some_function);
```

instead of

```
 this.some_button.click(this.some_function); // Result is undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Chang your code to the following:

```
some_object = {
self = this,
some_variable: 0,
some_button: $('<input />', {
    type: "button",
    value: "Click Me"
}),
some_function: function () {
    alert(self.some_variable);
},
init: function () {
    $("body").append(self.some_button);
    this.some_button.click(self.some_function); // Result is undefined
}
}
some_object.init();
some_object.some_function(); // Result is 0
```